# How to show actual values involved in a Hql query?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I configured the app to show the sql queries :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.ambre.pta")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:jdbc.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:fr/global.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:fr/main.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:fr/admin.properties")

})
public class ApplicationContextConfig {

    ...

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {

        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);

        sessionBuilder.scanPackages("com.ambre.pta.model");
        sessionBuilder.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        sessionBuilder.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");

        return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();

    }

    ...

}
```

But at runtime the actual values involved in a query is not shown , instead there is just the `?` sign ! So how to enable the display of the actual values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the logger for category `org.hibernate.SQL` to debug and for `org.hibernate.type` to trace.

E.g. if you use log4j add this two lines to your configuration:

```
# SQL statements and parameters
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
```